# Oracle Converter Rdf report to Xml

Tags: oracle, report

I am trying to convert an .rdf report to xml.I am using report builder to convert but i cannot see an option for conversion to xml. I am new to this conversion process and i seem not to be getting a solution.I have been using forms and reports 18

Comment: Kindly add what you have tried till now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle has a tool called rwconverter.exe wich is installed among Developer Suite.
Please, verify the command line options for this tool in this link (10g):
http://docs.oracle.com/html/B10314_01/pbr_cla.htm#634712

Make sure you this is the proper version for you.

Comment: Hi @Itagyba i have forms and reports 18 installed.It does not have rwconverter.exe.It has RCON.EXE which i guess is the rwconverter.However, when I try using it to convert rdf to xml it does not have an option for conversion to xml.What am I missing?

Comment: You can find it at "Start Menu > Oracle Developer Suite > Reports Converter". Or in Oracle Devsuite install folder\BIN\rwconverter.exe

Ex.: C:\DevSuiteHome_1\BIN\rwconverter.exe